# Editing drupal theme menu css

Tags: css, drupal-7, template-engine, drupal-theming

I am new to drupal theme development. I am using `Fusion` as  my base theme and created a sub themed named `coldfusion`. My template.php is :

```
<?php
function coldfusion_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<div class="topmenu"><ul class="menu cold">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul></div>';
}
```

And my CSS is :

```
.topmenu
{
  height:30px;
  padding:4px 10px;
  background:#555;
}
.content.clearfix .menu.cold a
{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Though the background color `#555` appears for the `mainmenu`, same background also appears for the `admin shortcut menu`. I think my approach is wrong. Can you guide me what is the proper way? Thanks in advance
[image: Drupal menu]

Answer (score 0):

since you are modifying the template, and adding `<div class='topmenu'>`, you might as well add another class in there .. say ... `<div class='topmenu coldfusion'>` and use that as your css selector, as in

```
.topmenu.coldfusion {
    height:30px;
    padding:4px 10px;
    background:#555;
}
```

Comment: Where should I add the class? Adding a class in `function coldfusion_menu_tree($variables)` adds the class to both to the `mainmenu` and `admin shortcut menu` !

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. For a specific menu you override coldfusion_menu_tree__MENU_NAME for a specific menu. I've no idea what _MENU_NAME would be in your case though. I'm assuming you don't have a convenient selector difference currently in the two document areas ?